# Problem proving monotonicity while showing uniform convergence of $\sum_{k} \frac{1}{k} \sin \left ( \frac{\pi k^2}{x + k} \right )$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, uniform-convergence

## Remark

This is a homework type of question and since there is no homework tag anymore I ask you to *tell me how would you solve this (hints) and let me solve it for myself so I can practice.*

I can post the solution afterwards so next generations would have access to both hints and the full solution.

## Problem

Show uniform convergence of a series

$$
\sum_{k}\frac{1}{k} \sin \left ( \frac{\pi k^2}{x + k} \right )
$$
where $x \in \left ( 0, \frac{\pi}{2} \right )$. Use the identity $\sin(y - k \pi) = (-1)^k \sin(y)$.

## Partial solution

I defined
$$
f_k(x) = \frac{1}{k} \sin \left ( \frac{\pi k^2}{x + k} \right )
$$
and used the identity where $y = \frac{\pi k^2}{x + k}$.

That gives

$$
f_k(x) = \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k} \sin \left ( \frac{\pi k x}{x + k} \right ).
$$

Now I want to apply Dirichlet's theorem where $g_k(x) = (-1)^{k+1}$ which has bounded partial sums as needed.

Problem is with $h_k(x) = \frac{\sin \left ( \frac{\pi k x}{x + k} \right )}{k}$. It has to converge (as sequence) to zero. No problem at all if you consider $|h_k(x)| \leq \frac{1}{k} \rightarrow 0$ for $k \rightarrow \infty$. The real problem is with proving monotonicity of $h_k(x)$ (as a sequence) for $\forall x \in \left ( 0, \frac{\pi}{2} \right )$.

## Tried & failed

I've tried to calculate $\frac{\partial h_k(x)}{\partial k}$ and calculate it's stationary points.

$\frac{\partial h_k(x)}{\partial k}$ yields

$$
\frac{ \cos \left ( \frac{\pi k x}{x+k} \right ) \frac{\pi k x^2}{(k+x)^2} - \sin \left ( \frac{\pi k x}{x + k} \right )}{k^2}
$$
so $\frac{\partial h_k(x)}{\partial k} = 0$ is a nonlinear equation I am not able to solve.

The equation looks like this (after a few rearrangements)

$$
\cos \left ( \frac{\pi k x}{x+k} \right ) \pi k x^2 = \sin \left ( \frac{\pi k x}{x+k} \right ) (k+x)^2
$$

## Questions

- Is there a way to solve that equation?
- Is there another way to prove monotonicity of the function $h_k(x)$?
- Is there another way to prove convergence of the series $\sum_k f_k(x)$?

Comment: $\frac{\pi k x}{x+k} = \pi x - \frac{\pi x^2}{x+k}$, so your series is not too different from $\sin \pi x \sum \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k}$.

Comment: The problem is to break your series up into one term that is simple and easy to analyze, and another series that is more complicated, but which can be shown to converge absolutely uniformly. The inequality $|\sin s - \sin t| \leq |s - t|$ may help.

Comment: @user208259: I am sorry, but I still don't get it...

ad 1st comment: I see that if you take a limit $k \rightarrow \infty$ of the argument of the sine it converges to $\pi x$, but I don't know how to get rid of the $- \frac{\pi x^2}{x+k}$.

2nd comment: I can't see where I can use that inequality ($|\sin s - \sin t| \leq |s-t|$ because I don't get the diference of two sines there.

Comment: $\sin[\pi k x / (x+k)] = \sin \pi x + \varepsilon_k(x)$, where $\left|\varepsilon_k(x)\right| \leq \pi x^2/(x + k) \leq \pi^3/4k$.

Comment: Is this because $|\sin(x-y)| = |\sin x \cdot \cos y - \cos x \cdot \sin y| \leq |\sin x - \sin y| \leq | \sin(x) - y|$?

Comment: I'm not sure if a proof can be given along those lines, as there are many cases to look at depending on the signs of the terms. The point is that if $|f'(x)| \leq M$ on $[a,b]$, then $|f(b) - f(a)| \leq M(b-a)$ by the mean-value theorem. $|\sin'(x)| = |\cos x| \leq 1$.

Comment: Oh... $|\sin x \cdot \cos y - \cos x \cdot \sin y| \leq |\sin x - \sin y|$ is not true.

Comment: The derivative justification for the inequality you have given appeared to me intuitively at first, but I didn't make the connection to the mean value theorem. But I still don't get how you get $\sin(s) - \sin(t)$ from $\sin(s-t)$.

Comment: $|\sin[\pi k x/(x+k)] - \sin \pi x| \leq |\pi k x/(x+k) - \pi x|$.

Comment: I get this, but I don't get the step before. Is $|\sin(x-y)| \leq |\sin(x) - \sin(y)|$?

Comment: I'm not sure, but that's not the point. $|\sin(x-y) - \sin x| \leq |y|$ is more useful here. The point is that $\sin[\pi k x/(x+k)]$ is close to $\sin \pi x$, not that it is small in its own right. So you need to find a bound for $|\sin[\pi k x/(x+k)] - \sin \pi x|$, not for $|\sin[\pi k x/(x+k) - \pi x ]|$.

Comment: The point is that I can't see how you get $\sin[\pi k x /(x+k)] - \sin \pi x$ out of $\sin[\pi k x /(x+k)]$

Comment: As $k \to + \infty$, we have $\pi k x/(x+k) \to \pi x$. Therefore for large values of $k$, the quantity $\sin[\pi k x/(x+k)]$ can be expected to be close to $\sin \pi x$. So give the name $\varepsilon_k(x)$ to the difference of the two, and analyze how large that difference can be. It turns out that the part of the series corresponding to $\varepsilon_k(x)$ converges absolutely uniformly. The part corresponding to $\sin \pi x$ converges uniformly, though not absolutely. So you've broken something complicated into two parts, each of which is simpler to analyze, though for different reasons.

Comment: Thanks for help! Now I think finallly get it. Sorry for bothering you with so many questions.